# PHP MYSQLI - Selecting multiple rows grouped by month

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a series of news articles, that are stored inside a database, like so:

```
id
articleTitle
articleBody
articleBy
category
dateEntered
```

What I want to do is select all of the articles and group them by a particular month / year that they were entered. For example:

- May

  - News article 1
  - News article 2
  - News article 3
- Feb

  - News article 4
  - News article 5
  - News article 6

I am able to select the months, as well as how many items are there, using the following:

```
 SELECT id, articleTitle, YEAR(dateEntered) AS 'year', MONTH(dateEntered) AS 'month'  FROM News GROUP BY YEAR(dateEntered), MONTH(dateEntered) DESC
```

Whenever I try to output the contents of 'articleTitle' it only shows 1 result, when there should be 28 entries that are showing.

Where am I going wrong in my query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `GROUP BY` clause collapses sets of rows with common values for the expressions in the `GROUP BY` clause.  With this in your query:

```
GROUP BY YEAR(dateEntered), MONTH(dateEntered)
```

The query will only return a *single* row for distinct values of those expressions.  There is nothing wrong with doing this. This is convenient if you want to return a count of the number of rows that have that year and month, for example

```
  SELECT DATE_FORMAT(dateEntered,'%Y-%m')
       , COUNT(1) AS cnt_
    FROM mytable 
   GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(dateEntered,'%Y-%m')
```

If you don't want your query to "collapse" the rows, then don't use a `GROUP BY` clause.

---

I suspect you want to use an `ORDER BY` clause, not a `GROUP BY`. To make the order the rows are returned in more deterministic, you can add more expressions to the ORDER BY clause. Also note that `ASC` and `DESC` apply to *each* expression in the `ORDER BY` clause.

For example:

```
SELECT n.id
     , n.articleTitle
     , YEAR(n.dateEntered)  AS `year`
     , MONTH(n.dateEntered) AS 'month'
  FROM News n 
 ORDER
    BY YEAR(n.dateEntered)  DESC
     , MONTH(n.dateEntered) DESC
     , n.id                 DESC
```

Comment: This is is great, and works! But, how would I make it so that the  year-month only display once? Currently I have `while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))` but if I echo `$row['month']` it will display it for how many results there are?

Comment: @Phorce: It's better to handle that on the client side. Process the first row, save the value from `$row['month']` into another variable e.g. `$prev_month`. On the next row, compare the value from the row to the value saved from the last row. If they are equal, then don't output the value, otherwise, output it (because it's a "new" value.)